# How can I make Mockito.verify ignore other type parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a GenericCreator, with the following method

```
<E extends Entity> E create(E entity);
```

I want to assert this method (where E = Foo) is only called once. I don't care if it's called with any other type parameter. The following assertion does not work for me:

```
 verify(genericCreator).create(any(Foo.class));
```

because in the following case:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = new Bar();
genericCreator.create(foo);
genericCreator.create(bar);
```

it throws `org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooManyActualInvocations: 
genericCreator.create(<any>); Wanted 1 time .... But was 2 times ...`
While in reality I don't care about the .create(bar) call and I don't want the test to fail because it is called. How can I achieve this?

Comment: http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/latest/org/mockito/Mockito.html#4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `isA` matcher for invocations where you care about the specific type.

http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#isA(java.lang.Class)

The documentation for `any` notes that it does not actually check types -- it's simply there to let you avoid casting. Thus, verifying with any accepts an object of any type -- this is why you get 2 calls instead of 1.